# AS3 - Not sure what it's called

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flixel

I'm writing a game that involves cargo, and I plan to have a large number of cargo types. Currently I have a `Cargo` class, and a ship carrying cargo has an array of the `Cargo`s it is holding.

I'd really rather not have each ship with a bunch of objects when all I really want to know is how much of which cargoes each ship has. Especially when these ships will be created and discarded a lot.

I'm sure the thing I'm looking for is so basic I'll look dumb for even asking, but I know there's something similar to an array that holds an object and a related value. I want to use that to reference the `Cargo` type from the static array, and hold the quantity.

What's it called? How would I use it (ie what are common functions used for it)? Some code snippets and terminology would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) class. It's similar to arrays (which use integer indexes) or objects (which can be used as string based, associative arrays). A Dictionary uses objects as unique keys that get mapped to a single value.

I think you don't need one though. A global variable is rarely a good idea. I wouldn't unnecessarily complicate this and just let each ship handle it's own cargo, maybe by using a quantity as AaronLS [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479024/as3-not-sure-what-its-called#8479157). But don't worry too much about performance here, even if you create and destroy thousands of ships each frame, rendering them will take significantly more time than the handling of arrays.

Anyway, here's how you use a dictionary and some things to consider. It doesn't have much special methods, it's used almost like an array.

```
var dict = new Dictionary();
var key:MyClass = new MyClass(); // a key can be of any class 

dict[key] = "foo"; // set a value
trace( dict[key] ); // traces: foo

dict[key] = null; // set value to null, key is still there. It won't get garbage collected!
delete dict[key]; // remove the key
```

Consider using [new Dictionary(true)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html#Dictionary%28%29) to avoid the garbage collection issue.

Comment: If you're that worried about performance, consider googling Object Pooling (and pool your ships)

Comment: @Amy Blankenship the dictionary object performs faster than the vector, array, or any object lookup method in actionscript 3.

Comment: You can use a Dictionary to store your object pool, or any other type of storage that can store more than one thing.

Comment: @AscensionSystems Actually OP just asked about a data structure. I'm quite sure he meant the `Dictionary` class.

Comment: @kapep: "I'd really rather not have each ship with a bunch of objects when all I really want to know is how much of which cargoes each ship has". - Dictionary object would be a key/value pair method of storing a bunch of objects, weather those objects are simple base types like ints and numbers or complex classes.

Comment: @AscensionSystems "the thing I'm looking for is [...] similar to an array that holds an object and a related value. I want to use that to reference the Cargo type from the static array, and hold the quantity. What's it called?". It sounds like he wants to use cargo types as keys, and quantities as values. "when all I really want to know is how much of which cargoes each ship has" shouldn't be done by using a variable for each single cargo type. Wouldn't be very scalable. (in the ship's class, if that what you meant in the other comment)

Answer (score 3):

Just make your cargo class contain a Quantity property.

Or you could have a CargoType class, which contains information about the type of Cargo(i.e. whether its some food, or money, or guns).  Then you Cargo class would have a CargoType property and a Quantity property.

This way your array for the ship's cargo would only have a Cargo of each type and the Quantity property is used to indicate how many.

Comment: To answer the question more simply, it's called a variable. :D var totalItemsInCargo:uint = N; var totalCargoWeight:Number = Z * N; etc.